# Retrieve *only* the ALAssetsGroup corresponding to the "Camera Roll"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have been following this guide:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/

However, this example calls the `assetGroupEnumerator` with all of the different `ALAssetGroup`s that correspond to photo albums.

In my case, I only want the Camera Roll. What is the best way to do this? Is there some mask I can pass to `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` besides `ALAssetsGroupAlbum`that will only return the anointed album representing photos actually taken by/saved on the device?

I assume simply comparing its name to the string "Camera Roll" will only work on iOS devices whose locale is set to English. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos` for your mask and you should only receive the Camera roll (née Saved Photos album on camera-less devices).